# Why onbeforeunload doesn't fire if page is not clicked?

Tags: javascript

I just want to learn why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>close</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>onbeforeunload</h1>

<script>
    console.log("loaded");
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(){
        console.log("closed");
        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you copy and save this code as a .html file and run it in browser and don't click inside the page and close the tab or browser, then the onbeforeunload won't fire!

But if you click once inside the page, and then try to close the page, it works all fine as it should.

Comment: Maybe you close it too soon, before that JS has chance to execute.

Comment: No, the page is loaded and the console.log shows "loaded" string. Try it please.

Comment: Or maybe it's browser security mechanism, to hinder unwanted popups/popunders, or something like that.

Comment: I tried it on Chrome, Mozilla and iExplorer. they all act the same

Comment: There is something about the first click inside the page....what does it trigger?

Comment: refer to this [mozzila onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) it states that until -unless the users interact with the page it will not be fired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> **Note**: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in `beforeunload` event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all. For a list of specific browsers, see the [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility) section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log("loaded");
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(){
        console.log("closed");
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>onbeforeunload</h1>
```

Comment: There's really no need to involve jquery here.

Comment: I have added it for test purpose.